# Using Marathon json to create new implementations

Tags: docker, mesos, marathon

We've been exploring marathon to deploy into a docker cluster. In the application architecture, we have a postgresql database which the application server need to access.

In the development stage, we relied on fig to create links between dockers and then use the environment variables imposed by the docker to connect to destination (app server to postgresql)

Yet, in Marathon we could not find a similar approach, we tried to use dependencies but that did not work, below is our Marathon.json file

```
{
    "id": "/project",
    "groups": [
        {
            "id": "apps",
            "apps": [
                {
                    "id": "app",
                    "mem": 1024,
                    "env": {
                        "APP_HOME": "/var/lib/app",
                        "GIT_BRANCH": "release/2.0.0",
                        "SETTING_FILE": "development",
                        "BROKER_URL": "redis://redis_1:6379/0"
                    },
                    "dependencies": ["database", "caching", "messaging"],
                    "container": {
                        "type": "DOCKER",
                        "docker": {
                            "image": "xxx/aok:app"
                        }
                    },
                    "volumes": [
                        {
                            "containerPath": "/var/lib/app",
                            "hostPath": ".",
                            "mode": "RW"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "celery",
                    "mem": 1024,
                    "env": {
                        "APP_HOME": "/var/lib/app",
                        "GIT_BRANCH": "release/2.0.0",
                        "SETTING_FILE": "development",
                        "BROKER_URL": "redis://redis_1:6379/0"
                    },
                    "container": {
                        "type": "DOCKER",
                        "docker": {
                            "image": "xxx/aok:celery"
                        }
                    },
                    "volumes": [
                        {
                            "containerPath": "/var/lib/app",
                            "hostPath": ".",
                            "mode": "RW"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "celeryhb",
                    "mem": 1024,
                    "env": {
                        "APP_HOME": "/var/lib/app",
                        "GIT_BRANCH": "release/2.0.0",
                        "SETTING_FILE": "development",
                        "BROKER_URL": "redis://redis_1:6379/0"
                    },
                    "container": {
                        "type": "DOCKER",
                        "docker": {
                            "image": "xxx/aok:celeryhb"
                        }
                    },
                    "volumes": [
                        {
                            "containerPath": "/var/lib/app",
                            "hostPath": ".",
                            "mode": "RW"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "database",
            "apps": [
                {
                    "id": "pg",
                    "mem": 1024,
                    "container": {
                        "type": "DOCKER",
                        "docker": {
                            "image": "mughrabi/aok:pg"
                        },
                        "volumes": [
                            {
                                "containerPath": "/var/lib/postgresql/data",
                                "hostPath": "/tmp/aok-postgres-data",
                                "mode": "RW"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "caching",
            "apps": [
                {
                    "id": "redis",
                    "mem": 1024,
                    "container": {
                        "type": "DOCKER",
                        "docker": {
                            "image": "redis"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "messaging",
            "apps": [
                {
                    "id": "rabbitmq",
                    "mem": 1024,
                    "container": {
                        "type": "DOCKER",
                        "docker": {
                            "image": "rabbitmq"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Can someone please advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into using something like Consul https://www.consul.io/ or etcd https://github.com/coreos/etcd